# Rails Nested Form Error Creates Duplicate Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've got a form in Rails that creates a user as well as a project.

Here's the form code from the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects, allow_destroy: true
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable

  def with_project
    self.projects.build
    self  
  end  
end
```

and the form view:

```
= form_for [resource_name, resource], url: registration_path(resource_name) do |u|
  = u.fields_for :projects do |p| 
    .field = p.text_field :service
    .field = p.text_field :location

  .field = u.email_field :email

  .actions = u.submit "Click to continue"
```

and the user `registrations_controller.rb`:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters


  def new

    build_resource({}).with_project
    set_minimum_password_length
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  private

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u|
      u.permit(:email, project: [:id, :service, :location, :_destroy])
    }
  end

end
```

The form works as expected; however, when submitted without an email the view shows two fields for `:service` and `:location`

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Update - here's my `routes.rb` (now the problem is that the project_fields are not appearing in my form view at all).

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "users/registrations"}
devise_scope :user do
  root 'users/registrations#new'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Arup. Can you point out any specific mistakes?

Comment: You need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and you also need to modify the _strong_param_ declaration. Now please read the link I gave.

Comment: I did read the link you gave. Updated my question with the User model code (which contains accepts_nested_attributes_for as it should).

Comment: Also modified the strong_params (changed :project to :projects_attributes); however, none of this fixes the error that I'm asking about.

Comment: What do you mean with "when submitted without an email the view shows two fields for `:service` and `:location`"? Does it show twice the fields when you reload the form after submitting it a first time? Just a suggestion in the meanwhile: `ProjectsController` is irrelevant in this case, your projects are created by `RegistrationsController`.

Comment: correct - when the form is submitted without an `:email` the view displays two fields for `:service`, two fields for `:location` and one field for `:email` when it should only display one `:service` and one `:location` field.

Comment: Where do you call the `with_project` instance method?

Comment: it's defined in the User model; however, I don't think it's being called anywhere. Probably should be called in the RegistrationsController, correct?

Comment: Isn't that because you just created a new project when submitting your form and therefore it lists it when refreshed? How are the fields doubled? Also what is the submit action of your form?

Comment: @AndrewHendrie Your code does not reflect the error you are facing, however my hunch is that `self.projects.build` is run every time your validation fails, causing your records to duplicate

Comment: You might be calling `with_project` somewhere in create action I guess. Can you post entire controller code

Comment: with_project is actually being called in the view... can I put it somewhere else instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im going to make an assumption on your controller, the code may not be exactly this.

```rb
def new
  @user = User.new.with_projects
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user]).with_projects #this is where your problem is.
end
```

The `params[:user]` contains `project_attributes`, which are assigned to a project but not persisting. When you call `with_projects` it will add another unpersisted project onto your `User` instance. Since `projects` is a `has_many` fields for treats it as a collection. So `fields_for` essentially performs a loop over the existing projects persisted and unpersisted. This is why you are seeing duplicate fields for service and location. You have *two* projects.

As I mentioned previously, this may not be exactly how you have it setup but it *is* what is happening.

## Update:

As the question has been updated...

The problem is in the form. Exactly the same as above is happening but in different places. The form is rendered once, in the `new` view(which is rendered by the `new` action), which builds the `Project` instance on the `User` instance. The forum is submitted, assigning one instance of `Project` to `@user`. The `create` action then fails as there is no valid email field. The `create` action then renders the create view(which in turn renders the `form` partial again. The form then builds another instance of `project` associated with the User.

You can solve the problem by moving it to the only place it is required. The `new` action. See the example.

The finished code should look something like:
Controller:

```rb
def new
  @user = User.new.with_projects
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  #..... etc
end
```

form:

```rb
= form_for [resource_name, resource], url: registration_path(resource_name) do |u|
  // etc.....
```

Comment: with_project is being called in my form_for tag - where should I move it?

Comment: When I remove `with_project` from the form tag the `fields_for :projects` fields don't appear on my page

Comment: @AndrewHendrie put it into the `new` action in the controller.

Comment: sorry - should have mentioned that I did that as well (I'll update the controller code in my question)

Comment: @AndrewHendrie please include your create action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104874/discussion-between-andrew-hendrie-and-dickieboy).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the RegistrationsController again calls the method when with_project render the new action, so the form displays two fields for location and service.